# Convert string array from a file into an int array without Number Format Exception

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

My assignment is to perform a merge sort function in java. I have the merge sort function figured it out already. The problem I have with this assignment is to convert each line of integers of a text file and perform merge sort function to each of them. For example:
3 
4 25 5 29 6
12 64 23 11 32
94 12 42 23 55

The first line is the number of arrays contained in the file, and the next 3 lines below are the arrays that I need to perform merge sort. So I need to do merge sort on arrays like 4 25 5 29 6, 12 64 23 11 32, and 94 12 42 23 55.

What I tried to do is to create four separate string arrays to store each line of integers, so I used the nextLine() method from the scanner. The problem I am dealing right now is to figure out how to convert them as int arrays without dealing number format exceptions.

This is my Merge Sort function class

```
public class MergeSort 
{
   private int[] array;
   private int[] tempMergArr;
   private int length;

public void sort(int inputArr[]) 
{
    this.array = inputArr;
    this.length = inputArr.length;
    this.tempMergArr = new int[length];
    doMergeSort(0, length - 1);
}

public void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) 
{

    if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) 
    {
        int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
        // Below step sorts the left side of the array
        doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);
        // Below step sorts the right side of the array
        doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);
        // Now merge both sides
        mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
    }
}


public void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) 
{

    for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
        tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
    }
    int i = lowerIndex;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = lowerIndex;
    while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) {
        if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= middle) {
        array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

}
}
```

This is the driver class of Merge Sort, this is where the problem lies.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergeSortDriver 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    String[] array = new String[6];
    String[] array1 = new String[6];
    String[] array2 = new String[6];
    String[] array3 = new String[6];


    int i = 0;
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);


        array[i] = fileReader.nextLine();
        array1[i] = fileReader.nextLine();
        array2[i] = fileReader.nextLine();
        array3[i] = fileReader.nextLine();
        System.out.println(array1[i]);
        System.out.println(array2[i]);
        System.out.println(array3[i]);


    fileReader.close();

    MergeSortDriver driver = new MergeSortDriver();

    for(int j = 0; j<array1.length; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(driver.convertToInt(array1)[i]+" ");
    }



    /* 
    int[] inputArr = {4,25,5,29,6}; // if I do like this, then the code will work, so the string arrays need to be like this in order to work.
    MergeSort mms = new MergeSort();
    mms.sort(inputArr);
    for(int i:inputArr)
    {
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    */
}
public static int[] convertToInt(String[] array)
{
    int[] ints = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return ints;
}


}
```

I hope you guys can find out the errors inside my driver class source code, if you try to run the program right now, you will get number format exception. So my goal is to convert string arrays from the file into int arrays without generating exceptions.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Too much code for your basic question. In Java 8+, you might `split` a given line by one or more white space(s) and then use a `Stream` and `mapToInt` like

```
String line = "4 25 5 29 6";
int[] arr = Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

in earlier versions you can do something similar, but it requires a little more code - like

```
String line = "4 25 5 29 6";
String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s+");
int[] arr = new int[lineParts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < lineParts.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[i]);
}
```